# Why did we use return here in Recursive Function?

Tags: c++, recursion, return, function-call

Why did  we use return here in this code in Doubly Linked List Lecture ? When I run the code , the recursion takes place without writing the return kw,Why do we need it then?

```
Node* reverseusingRecursion(Node* &prev,Node* &curr){
  //*base condition
  if (curr==NULL)
  {
    //*LL has been reversed
    return prev;
  }
   //* 1 case solve rest will be taken care by recursion function(This is the basic escence of a recursive function)
   Node* forward=curr->next;
        curr->next=prev;
        prev=curr;
        curr=forward;

        return reverseusingRecursion(prev,curr);

}
```

I have written code without using return in * return reverseusingRecursion(prev,curr);* and it works fine.
Why do we need to enter return then?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6cnb.jpg)

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). If you don't return the node, how is the caller going to retrieve the new head of the list, which used to be the tail in the old list? You have to pass it back up the call stack. How is the caller using this code? By the way, this algorithm is a poor fit for recursion because you can easily blow the call stack, in addition to being more confusing to write than a loop. [tag:dsa] isn't for data structures & algorithms.

Comment: *it works fine* Only by misfortune. You promise that `reverseusingRecursion` always returns a `Node*`, so removing that `return` means your code have Undefined Behaviour, and your program is allowed to do absolutely anything, including [making demons fly out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: Functions return values by putting them in a special place. When returning multiple levels in a recursive function, the inner level *might* have placed the value in the expected place, and an outer level can stumble over it by chance. To make it work "for real", you have to return values at each level.

Comment: _Side Note:_ Since C++11, `NULL` has no place in C++. Use `nullptr` instead.

Comment: The function has a non-`void` return type, so must return via a `return` statement (as opposed to "falling off the end") to avoid undefined behaviour.   One nasty feature (hypothetical in theory, but actually happens in practice) of undefined behaviour is, as you are experiencing, it *seems* to work in testing - until something unrelated changes (compiler update, operating system update, program being used by an end user who is not a developer) and suddenly the program stops working as intended.

Answer (score -1):

The function must return a pointer to the new head node of the reversed list. The pointer to the new head node is obtained in the last recursive call of the function. So all preceding recursive calls of the function must return the pointer obtained and returned in the last recursive call of the function. Without the return statement the returned pointer is undefined.

The function can work as expected accidently if due to the generated object code the function places the pointer `prev` in a register that is used by the compiler to return a value from the function. But this is not guaranteed.

You always must write a valid C code and do not rely on the generated by a compiler object code..